# Java replace pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace the ROOMS start and end tag from an xml file.

```
<A><ROOMS><B></B></ROOMS></A>
```

becomes

```
<A><B></B></A>
```

And also

```
<A><ROOMS><B></B></ROOMS></A>
```

becomes

```
<A><B></B></A>
```

I tried

```
Pattern.compile("\\\\\\\\<(.*)ROOMS\\\\\\\\>").matcher(xml).replaceAll("")
```

, but it does not work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why would that regex work?

Comment: What is with the 8 backslashes?

Comment: Why are you using regex and not an XML parser?

Comment: The regex doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @MattBall you don't need an XML parser to remove some tags.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm constrained by my client, I have to perform this replace with the xml as a string.

Comment: Why REGEX?. Just use String#replace();

Comment: try this </?([A-Z])\w+>  as regex, but your rule is not yet clear.

Comment: @clcto - You don't *need* an XML parser to remove tags but it certainly makes the code much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/636009

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is absurd. Just use:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll( "</?ROOMS>", "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this regex :

```
<[\/]?ROOMS>
```

Comment: You don't sound too sure.

Comment: It is just one of the way to do it. There are many ways to match this regex. That is why I used probably.

Comment: With this pattern I get </A> instead of <A><B></B></A>

Comment: My bad, edited it. Please try it now. This will work. Have tested it.

Comment: @JBalaguero: Try this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<[/]?ROOMS>
```

as your pattern.  It uses the `?` flag to indicate that the XML-closing forward slash should occur 0 or 1 times.

Comment: `/` has no special meaning in regexes, so you don't need to enclose it in square brackets or escape it with a backslash.